# Не могу заменить стандартную стрелку select. старую стрелку убираю, а новая не добавляется

Tags: html

```css
.form-line{
  position: relative;
select{
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
select::after{
  content: url(../img/select-arrow.svg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-line">
  <div class="label">Район доставки</div>
  <select class="text">
    <option value="">Выбрать</option>
    <option value="kharkov">Харьков</option>
    <option value="kiev">Киев</option>
    <option value="odessa">Одесса</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка синтаксиса, вы забыли закрыть блок у `.form-line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у select'а не может быть псевдоэлемента. Сделайте через background:

```css
select{
  width: 110px;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: url(https://img.icons8.com/material-two-tone/2x/arrow.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-line">
  <div class="label">Район доставки</div>
  <select class="text">
    <option value="">Выбрать</option>
    <option value="kharkov">Харьков</option>
    <option value="kiev">Киев</option>
    <option value="odessa">Одесса</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы от placeholder'a был равный отступ для нескольких select

Comment: @ДмитрийЛюба, не понял. Поясните.

Comment: У меня есть несколько .form-line с select. В первом select placeholder="text". Во втором select placeholder="text text text". Мне нужно, чтобы margin-right от плейсхолдера до стрелки был одинаковым. А в вашем примере мне для каждого selecta нужно прописывать background-position

Comment: @ДмитрийЛюба `placeholder` используется для `<input>`, причём тут `<select>`?

Comment: @ДмитрийЛюба, причём тут margin-right? Положение стрелки определяется с помощью background-position, а расстояние от текста до стрелки - шириной select'а. Посмотрите мой код внимательно - я там задал эти параметры. Можете изменять их так, как Вам нужно.

Comment: @ΝNL993, автор видимо имеет в виду текст в первом option, называя его плейсхолдером

Comment: Ой. прошу прощения, заработался. Не placeholder, а option

Comment: как мне сделать, чтобы от первого option расстояние до стрелки было одинаковым

Comment: @ДмитрийЛюба не совсем понял... Разве option не уже во всю ширину select'а?