# Стрелка в select

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы расстояние от первого `option` до стрелки было фиксированным. Я хотел первому `option` дать псевдоэлемент и задать ему `margin-left: 11px`, но не работает.

Получается нужно элементу `select` прописать `background-image` и каждому этому элементу задать `background-position`. Или есть другое решение?

```css
select {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

option {
  font-family: "TTNormsPro-Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
}

option:first-child::after {
  content: url(https://img.icons8.com/material-two-tone/2x/arrow.png);
  margin-left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-line">
  <div class="label">Район доставки</div>
  <select class="text">
    <option value="">Выбрать</option>
    <option value="kharkov">Харьков</option>
    <option value="kiev">Киев</option>
    <option value="odessa">Одесса</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-line">
  <div class="label">Способ оплаты</div>
  <select class="Когда заберете?">
    <option value="skoro">В ближайшее время</option>
    <option value="card">На этой неделе</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть только несколько атрибутов стиля, которые можно применить к элементу `option` и `background` не в их числе. Это связано с тем, что этот тип элемента является примером «замещенного элемента». Они зависят от ОС и не являются частью HTML/браузера. Его нельзя стилизовать с помощью CSS. Ознакомьтесь с [документацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу заменить стандартную стрелку select. старую стрелку убираю, а новая не добавляется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451758/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-select-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4)

Comment: @Simon, внимательно читайте вопрос: background задаётся select'у, а не option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Option>`-ы - это то, что показано ПОД `<select>`-ом при его раскрытии. Они стилятся, но а) ограниченно и б) вам не поможет.

Когда в `<select>`-е что-то выбрано, отображаемое содержимое - это уже НЕ `<Option>`, а взятый из него текст. На него влияют стили `<select>`-а. И эти стили тоже далеко не все применимы.

В вашем случае можно попробовать, например, так:

- сделать `<select>`-у прозрачный цвет текста ,фона и бордера (но при этом не забыть задать цвет и фон `<Option>`-ам)
- и под него подложить нужного вида `<div>`, в котором будет `<span>`, которому:

  1. задать стиля `padding-right:**px; background-image:***;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center right;`
  2. задать ID.
  3. при изменении (выборе значения)
     `<select>`-а яваскриптом совать его `value` в этот `<span>`.

Но вот это все костылить ради сомнительного дизайна?..